# Ember.js - Removing data from Firebase with EmberFire

Tags: javascript, ember.js, firebase, emberfire

I'm using EmberFire to connect my DB with my wee Ember.js app. When I call `destroyRecord()` I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
App.MainUsersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    delete : function(user) {
      var thisUser = this.store.find(user)
      thisUser.destroyRecord()
    }
  }
})

App.MainUsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return this.store.findAll('users');
  }
});

App.Users = DS.Model.extend({});
```

**EDIT**

I've added a `User` model per suggested answer but I'm lost on the syntax.

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  user: DS.store.findAll('user')
});
```

I tried just having `store.findAll('user')` but `store` was `undefined`.

Sorry, not only am I learning Ember, Emberfire, but I'm also learning EmberData. Woo

Comment: Here's a simple example that should help get you started. (updated link) http://emberjs.jsbin.com/boharifi/10/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`store.find()` takes a type and id and then returns a promise, so try something like this:

```
this.store.find('user', user).then(function(user) {
  user.destroyRecord();
});
```

Also, you should create an `App.User` model (singular) and then use `store.findAll('user')`

I wrote the EmberFire bindings so let me know if you have any additional questions or feedback.

Comment: Awesome. That actually brings me a bit closer. For the `App.User` model, I'm not sure of the proper syntax. I'll post an update to the question